# DOM to use with SpiderMonkey?

Tags: javascript, python, dom, spidermonkey

I'm trying to use the GoogleMaps JavaScript library from inside of SpiderMonkey using the python wrapper, but I can't because of the lack of a DOM.

Is there some way I can integrate a DOM into this so that I can get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[env.js](http://github.com/thatcher/env-js) implements the DOM. I know it at least works in SpiderMonkey and Rhino but SpiderMonkey may have issues with things like XMLHttpRequest.